# Zyxel NAS326 not getting IP after powerloss

Tags: networking, router, ip, nas, dhcp

I bought a Zyxel NAS 326 and configured my router to a static IP. (192.168.0.110)

After power loss, I can't connect to the NAS (the IP is not responding). Every time I need to disconnect physically the RJ45 cable and reconnect it, after this the NAS works fine / it gets IP from the router.

What is the solution for this?

(I'm not sure, but I think the NAS powers on faster that the router)

Thanks advanced

Comment: NAS powering on before the router doesn’t matter. The router will assign the IP to the NAS when it initializes

Comment: It is strange, that after disconnecting and connecting the RJ45 on the NAS side, everything works fine. :| (After power loss, the router and NAS starts automatically, but the NAS does not work - I mean that I can't connect to the NAS-, util I reconnect the RJ45 plug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem I think it was, that:**

on the NAS side I saved the IP configuration,
but NOT on the Router side. (I thought I saved it)

The NAS seems to work now.